# Initialize data frame in R with column names

Tags: r, dataframe, initialization

I am trying to initialize a data frame with column names a, b, c WITHOUT any data:

```
 dfrm <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> "Error in data.frame(a, b, c) : object 'a' not found"

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: How about `dfrm <- data.frame(a = NULL, b = NULL, c = NULL)`?

Comment: @jazzurro: good idea but doesn't work.

Comment: That would make my column names X1, X2, X3 instead of a, b, c

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for that. Now Richard suggested the answer. I will have a look. :)